# List of Windows "real" users using Win32 API

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to get a list of the real users on the local machine. By real I mean the users
that can physically logon to the system and use it, excluding remote only accounts and the like.

This is what I do already.

- Call `NetUserEnum()` with `FILTER_NORMAL_ACCOUNT`.

  I get the following users:

  - __ vmware_user __
  - Administrator
  - Help Assistant
  - ASPNET
  - Guest
  - SUPPORT_xxxxxx

  Note that this are the same users that I get when calling net user from the command line,
  but in the logon dialog I can only select Administrator. This is what I want.
- From the return list on `NetUserEnum()`, I can tell which accounts are disabled. That leaves:

  - __ vmware_user __
  - Administrator
  - ASPNET
  - SUPPORT_xxxxxx
- Then I run `LsaEnumerateAccountRights()` to check which accounts have the SeInteractiveLogonRight.

  All of them have it. Except the real one, Administrator. Some of them have SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight.
  That leaves me with:

  - __ vmware_user __
  - Administrator (no SeInteractiveLogonRight)

I found somewhere that maybe I should be checking group permissions first, as my user account might be inheriting SeInteractiveLogonRight. So far, I haven't found a way to list the groups for a given account (SID or name). Tried with `NetUserGetGroups()` but it turns out that this one only returns domain groups (in my case, "None").

Right now I don't know what else to try. Looks like everything will be easier if I had an 'Access Token' but there seems to be no way of getting that for a user other than the currently logged on.
There are like 20 different APIs related to authentication and this is crazy.

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, the last step probably is just filter the users which belong to Administrators or Users group.

Try the method [NetUserGetLocalGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for enumerating the groups an user belongs to.

Comment: Thanks, that made it! I totally missed this NetUserGetLocalGroups() function.

Comment: For the record, my final solution to the problem is listing user's groups with this function, then keeping the users belonging to Users or Administrators group. I was checking permissions for users/groups with disabled local login, but turned out that windows is including these users into the logon list (though you can't actually log in, as they are disabled).